# Await for Pinia store state to load before performing a firestore query

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, pinia

I'm working on a Vue application that should list a user's transactions. I use Pinia to store the user ID which I then use in my Firestore query to filter the transactions belonging to the user.

When I first log in or navigate through the app, my query runs without a problem. But if I refresh the browser, the query fails. It seems the store doesn't load fast enough before executing the query.

What I can do?

```
     const transactions = ref(null);

      const store = useSession();
      const user_id = store.user_id;

      const q = query(
        colRef,
        where("user_id", "==", user_id),
        orderBy("created_at", "desc"),
        limit(30)
      );

      const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        console.log("unsub");
        let results = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        });

        transactions.value = results;
      });
```

I have tried to move the constant definition to an async await function and the query definitio to the then statement without success

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using localStorage as recommended in this post
[Refresh-proof your Pinia Stores](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/refresh-proof-your-pinia-stores/)

After installing @vueuse/core, I change my store code to this:

```
import {useLocalStorage} from "@vueuse/core";

export const useSession = defineStore("session", {
id: "store",
state: () => ({state: () => ({
user_id: useLocalStorage("user_id", ""),
}),
```